# Product of upper-triangular matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

** I´m trying to solve this problem, but I don´t now how to start, I think could be by induction but I´m not sure.  **

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $F$ be a field. Let $A_1, . . . , A_n$ be upper-triangular matrices in $M_{n×n}(F)$ satisfying the condition that the $(i, i)$-entry in $A_{i}$ is equal to $0$ for $1 ≤ i ≤ n$. Show that $A_1 · · ·A_n = O$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A_i$ are upper-triangular matrices with $(i,i)$-entry being equal to $0$, we can assume that 
$$
A_i=[0\space a_ie_1\space A_{i1}], \space a_i\in F, \space e_1=[1,0,\cdots,0]^T
$$
$A_{i1}$ is $n\times (n-2)$ submatrix. Then 
$$
A_1A_2=[0\space A_1a_2e_1\space A_1A_{21}]=[0\space a_20\space A_1A_{21}]=[0\space 0\space b_1e_1 \space A_{22}]
$$
$b_1\in F, A_{22}$ is $n\times (n-3)$ submatrix ($A_1e_1=0 $ for it is the 1st column of $A_1$).

Similarly
$$
A_1A_2A_3=[0\space 0\space b_1e_1 \space A_{22}][0\space a_3e_1\space A_{31}]=[0\space 0\space 0\space A_{33}]
$$
$A_{33}$ is $n\times (n-3)$ submatrix.

Repeat above process, we have
$$
A_1A_2\cdots A_n=0
$$